# Рекурсивное удаление элементов многомерного массива

Tags: php

Добрый день. Пытаюсь удалить рекурсивно определенные элементы из многомерного массива, но чего - то не получается. Использую php 5.3.

```
public static function removemainfilterGroup($arr)
{
    //$temp = $arr;
    $temp = array(
    'qwe'=>'test',
    'eqw'=>array(
        'sxf'=>'test',
        'asd'=>'test',
        'zc'=>array(
            'dsf'=>'test',
            'filter_group'=>'2',
            'gb'=>'test'
        ),
        'jh'=>'test',
        'hh'=>'test'
        ),
    'ytu'=>'test',
    'uy'=>array(
        'io'=>'test',
        'filter_group'=>'2',
        'yu'=>'test'
    ),
    'hjk'=>'test'
    );
    self::recursiveRemoval($temp);
    var_dump($temp);
    exit;
    $arr = array_values($arr);
    return $arr;
}

private static function recursiveRemoval(&$array)
{
    if(is_array($array))
    {
        foreach($array as $key=>&$arrayElement)
        {
            if(is_array($arrayElement))
            {
                self::recursiveRemoval($arrayElement);
            }
            else
            {
                if($key == 'filter_group' &&  $arrayElement == '2')
                {
                    unset($array);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе

```
array(5) { ["qwe"]=> string(4) "test" ["eqw"]=> array(5) { ["sxf"]=> string(4) "test" ["asd"]=> string(4) "test" ["zc"]=> array(3) { ["dsf"]=> string(4) "test" ["filter_group"]=> string(1) "2" ["gb"]=> string(4) "test" } ["jh"]=> string(4) "test" ["hh"]=> string(4) "test" } ["ytu"]=> string(4) "test" ["uy"]=> array(3) { ["io"]=> string(4) "test" ["filter_group"]=> string(1) "2" ["yu"]=> string(4) "test" } ["hjk"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

По идее из temp должны быть удалены ключи 'filter_group'. Но этого не происходит. Проверяю var_dump-ом саму функцию до unset.

```
if($key == 'filter_group' &&  $arrayElement == '2')
                {
                    var_dump($array);
                    exit;
                    unset($array);
                }
```

На выходе

```
array(3) { ["dsf"]=> string(4) "test" ["filter_group"]=> &string(1) "2" ["gb"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

Проверяю var_dump-ом саму функцию после unset.

```
if($key == 'filter_group' &&  $arrayElement == '2')
                {
                    unset($array);
                    var_dump($array);
                    exit;
                }
```

На выходе

```
NULL
```

Comment: `unset($array);`? Может все-таки `unset($array[$key]);`? Тогда `filter_group` будет удален

Comment: Нет, мне нужно удалить весь массив где находится ключ.

Comment: С unset($array[$key]); удаляется, но все же нужно удалить весь.

Comment: Вам, получается, надо удалить `zc` и `uy`? Ну тогда `$array = null`. Хотя здесь ключ все равно останется (будет `'zc' => null`), поэтому надо возвращать результат "наден-ненайден" и если надо, то удалять на уровне выше

Comment: Да мне нужно именно так, сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нет, мне нужно удалить весь массив где находится ключ.

Тогда выносите проверку выше. Не зачем бегать по ключам, если требуется узнать есть ли конкретный ключ, и его значение.
Точнее надо сначала проверить — а не удалить ли массив. Потом пробежаться рекурсией по вложенным массивам.

```
private static function recursiveRemoval(&$array, &$parent=null, $key=null) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) return;           

  if (array_key_exists('filter_group', $array)  && $array['filter_group']=='2') {
      if (is_array($parent)) { /* При первом вызове с одним параметром будет ложь, далее — истина. */
        unset ($parent[$key]);
      } else {
        unset ($array);
      }
      return;
  }

  foreach($array as $key=>&$arrayElement){
    if(is_array($arrayElement)) {
      self::recursiveRemoval($arrayElement, $array, $key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А вы пробовали ваш код запустить? Он не меняет исходный массив. Замена `unset ($array);` на `$array = null;` массив удаляет, но ключ сохраняет (т.е. получается `'zc' => null`)

Comment: Да бегать по ключам действительно было глупо, насчет $array = null получается мне потом еще раз запускать рекурсию и уже удалять пустые ключи, пока оставлю этот вариант про запас. Поищу способ формировать входящий массив без лишних ключей.

Comment: @VladimirChagin, я же вам в комменте к вопросу написал: надо возвращать результат "наден-ненайден" и если надо, то удалять на уровне выше.

Comment: @ВОРОН. Нет, не запускал. Сейчас пришёл домой — проверил, косяк реально был. Поправил, добавив отсыл к родительскому массиву.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все хорошо.